# Why is $h(x) = x^2 \sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ continuous at $0$, but $h'(x) = 2x \sin \big(\frac{1}{x} \big) - \cos \big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ not?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Given is this function

$$
h(x)=\begin{cases}
         x^2 \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)&\text{if}~\ x \ne 0\\
         0&\text{if}~\ x=0
       \end{cases}
$$

We want to examine if $h(x)$ is continuous everywhere as well as $h'(x)$.

Regarding $h(x)$ we have written the following:

For $x \neq 0$ the function $h(x)$ is continuous everywhere as a composition of continuous and differentiable functions.

Because of $\lim_{x\to0} h(x) = \lim_{x\to0} x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big) = 0 = h(0)$ it is also continuous at $0$ (as $\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ is bounded).

$$h'(x) = 2x \sin \bigg(\frac{1}{x} \bigg) - \cos \bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) \text{, x } \neq 0$$

It is $\lim_{x \to 0} h'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \big(2x \sin\big(\frac{1}{x} \big) - \cos \big( \frac{1}{x} \big) \big) \neq 0 = h'(0)$

$\Rightarrow h'$ is not continuous at  $x = 0$

I don't understand this explanation. Why can we not use the same argument (that $\sin\big(\frac{1}{x} \big))$ is bounded for the derivative as well?

[image]

Comment: the problem is $\cos(1/x)$ that obscillates too much and does not go to zero

Comment: You can't use the same argument because the term $\cos(1/x)$ isn't dominated by any factor that goes to $0$ as $x\to 0$. Note that the bounded $\sin(1/x)$ has an $x$ adjoined to it, and since this goes to $0$ as $x\to 0$, the same will be true of $x\sin(1/x)$. This is not the case with $\cos(1/x)$, so it will oscillate faster and faster between $1$ and $-1$ as $x\to 0$ and hence kill continuity of the derivative at $0$.

Comment: @AlannRosas How come it oscillates when the only difference between $\sin$ and $\cos$ is that $\cos$ is "shifted" from $\sin$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$? How can I find out that it oscillates if we want to figure it out by hand?

Comment: Notice how $\sin$ is being multiplied by something that is tending to zero. That is the critical thing that implies the term tends to zero, the fact that $\sin$ is bounded isn't enough by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are confused by the fact that the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} ~ x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$$ can be shown equal to $0$ by the boundedness of $\sin(1/x)$, whereas the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} ~ 2x\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)-\cos\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$$ does not exist at all - why can't we use the boundedness of $\sin(1/x)$ and $\cos(1/x)$ to evaluate this limit as well?

First of all, notice that limits of bounded functions do not necessarily exist. An easy-to-see example is $$\lim_{x\to 0} ~ (-1)^{\lfloor 1/x\rfloor}$$ So how is the boundedness of $\sin(1/x)$ used in the evaluation of the first limit? The factor of $x^2$ plays a crucial role. Because $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded *and* $x^2\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, we have that $$|x^2\sin(1/x)| = |x|^2 \cdot|\sin(1/x)| \leq C|x|^2$$ for some constant $C$ (a bound on the magnitude of $\sin(1/x)$), and $C|x|^2\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ for any $C>0$. Hence, we are applying the Squeeze Theorem in addition to the boundedness of $\sin(1/x)$. Now let's take a closer look at the second limit, and break it up into two terms: $2x\sin(1/x)$ and $-\cos(1/x)$. The former vanishes as $x\to 0$ by the same reasoning: we have $$|2x\sin(1/x)|=2|x|\cdot|\sin(1/x)|\leq 2C|x|$$ where $C$ is an upper bound on the magnitude of $\sin(1/x)$, and $2C|x|\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ for any $C>0$, hence by the Squeeze Theorem we have that $2x\sin(1/x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. But now think about the $-\cos(1/x)$ term. This term is bounded, but *it does not tend to zero*, for there is no extra factor of $x$ or $x^2$ to force this term to vanish as $x\to 0$. Instead, it (boundedly) oscillates infinitely many times as $x\to 0$.

In summary, although both $\sin(1/x)$ and $\cos(1/x)$ are bounded, the $\cos(1/x)$ term in the second limit is not being multiplied by an extra term which approaches zero, whereas the $\sin(1/x)$ terms in both limits are, forcing them to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part $2x*sin(\frac{1}{x})$ it is true. But cos(1/x)  x going to 0 takes any value between -1and +1 as often as you want. Why did you not see it in your graph?

Comment: I don't understand. What is $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ bounded by that $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is not?

Comment: sin(1/x) and cos (1/x) are bounded,  sin(1/x) and cos (1/x) are not  continuous at x=0. $ -1\le sin(x)\le 1$ are the bound for both.

Answer (score 1):

To verifie that the limit of derivative does not exist take the sequences $x_n\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{(2n+1) \pi n}$. Both of them converges to zero but $\cos (1/x_n)\to$ $1$ while $\cos (1/y_n) \to -1$ as $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to0} x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big) = 0 $ because $\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ is bounded, the function is dominated by $x^2$ which goes to $0$.

You cannot use the same argument for $ \lim_{x \to 0} \big(\cos \big( \frac{1}{x} \big) \big)$.
It would have worked if there was $x^2$ or $x$ (or any function of $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$) in front of $\cos$. Otherwise,
the limit is undefined. As $x$ goes closer to $0$, $\cos \big( \frac{1}{x} \big)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$.